# Why isn't JNIOnLoad running?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android project with a Java base Activity, Java JNI interface class, and native code. I have the proper

```
System.loadlibrary(_libraryname_);
```

In my Java interface class and from the logcat output:

```
11-29 15:11:20.737: D/dalvikvm(8940): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.testjni/lib/libTestJNI.so 0x406ef030, skipping init
```

In my cpp file header:

```
extern "C" {
   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNIOnLoad(JavaVM *, void *);
}
```

In the cpp file:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNIOnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
   LOGI("JNIOnLoad");
   jvm = vm;
   return JNI_VERSION_1_6; /* the required JNI version */
}
```

But still the OnLoad function never is called. I've tried uninstalling the app and re-installing it but it never runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function signature is [JNI_OnLoad](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_OnLoad). There is an **underscore / _** between **JNI** and **OnLoad**.

Comment: wow... you know when you've been staring at something for so long.